# Firebase not working Android Studio 3.0.1 [com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0]

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to sync with Firebase with my project I use the tool from Android Studio --> Firebase and then I do the steps (This is new Project) [Image](https://ibb.co/farpSn).
Android Studio version **3.0.1**

The build.gradle in App folder is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eranp.fiberbase"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The build.gradle in Project folder

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But when I sync the project I have this Error:

> Error:(13, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager.

But this is installed: [Image](http://ibb.co/gG0G7n).

I tried for a week to work with Firebase but anything working to sync.
How can I fix this?
thank you for helping!

Comment: go to *File -> settings -> SDK -> SDK Tools -> Check Install Build tools* and apply

Comment: Also not working :( https://ibb.co/cjvNf7

Comment: `imlementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0'` add this as dependency in gradle and change tye compileSdkVersion to 27

Comment: Error: https://ibb.co/ii6L07

Comment: that error is because of your `compileSdkVersion 26` change it to `compileSdkVersion 27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add this:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"
```

under the dependencies in the app/build.gradle

then you need to change the:

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
```

to this:

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
```

also update the firebase version to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

latest version

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a `compile` dependency to your project buildscript, which is not valid.  You are only supposed to add `classpath` dependencies to your buildscript, which effectively act as plugins for your Gradle build.

`compile` dependencies are to be using your app's build.gradle, which typically lives in the app folder.  These are SDK components that you use to build your app.

If you want to use `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"` in your app, move it from the buildscript dependencies to the app dependencies.

Comment: That looks like a completely different problem.

Comment: I know but how can I fix this?

Comment: If you have a problem that's different that the on you originally posted, please ask a different question.